# Creating Annual collections for future years

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to create a type of forecast based on outstanding balance, number of payments remaining and value of those payments. I have a data structure as per below

```
AccountNo|Balance   |Payments    |Frequency|PaymentsRemaining
12584    |1100      |100         |MX       |11
12887    |23656     |500         |MX       |47
13190    |2000      |22          |WK       |90
```

Balance is whats owed, payments are the month/weekly payments being made, frequency is Monthly or Weekly and remaining is remaining.

What i am trying to accomplish is calculating how much will be collected each year for the next 19 years as a separate column. Like so -

```
AccountNo|Balance  |Payments|Frequency|PaymentsRemaining|2014  |2015  |2016 |2017
12584    |1100     |100     |MX       |11               |1100  |0     |0    |0
12887    |23656    |500     |MX       |47               |568   |568   |568  |568
13190    |2000     |22      |WK       |90               |1144  |856   |     |
```

*Data is only an example and has been fabricated manually

I'm not even sure where to begin with attempting to replicate this in SQL as I have never had to create anything similar to this. I'm hoping i have given enough data and hope someone can assist me, even if its pointing me in a direction to pursue myself.

Comment: what is the difference between MX and WK ? Does that mean MX has 12 payments a year and WK has 48 ? If so why the Account 13190 only pay 12141 balance every year ? I don't get it !

Comment: @hoangnnm apologies, yes MK and WK is monthly and weekly, I had just done quick sums on balances. I've updated what I believe is the right figures. Thanks

Comment: ok, i'm still confused. Can you show for the formula to the results?

The first Account (12584) , balance is 1100, payments is 100, so each payment will be 1100/100 = 11, so with 11 payments remains, the total balance remains is 11*11 = 132, this is wrong according to your example results, but with Account 12887, the above formula is correct, I don't get it. 

By the way, please leave your correct and clear formula, i will get back to you with a solution after i arrive at work.

Comment: @hoangnnm Sorry I'm not being clear. The 1st table is the data I have available, all that is populated by a front end application apart from payments remaining, this is simply a balance / payment amounts. The 2nd table, more specificly the last 4 columns are the example of what data I want to create. There is no code for this at the moment. That's what I'm trying to replicate. How much would be paid in each year going forward for 19years based on payments remaining and how much is being paid each time. Hope this clears it up. Thanks

Comment: By asking you  to provide the formula, i mean can you show me how you calculate the example result(2nd table). 

This task is not hard on SQL, but i have to understand your example to help you. 

And i still have no idea how you calculate the incoming years's balance

Comment: @hoangnnm the data in the table was done manually by myself, it should be how much is collected in each year until the balance reaches zero. so with 11 payments remaining with a MX frequency the balance would be clear within 1 year. Meaning the collections appear for 2014 and then nothing for 2015 (if today was 1st Jan).

Comment: Let me make this clear. 

How come with a WK frequency (assuming there are always 52 weeks per year = 52 payments per year), 1012 payments remained can be full-paid in only 3 years ?

Comment: The data is just a sample I made up to give a rough idea of the desired output, I've updated it with a simpler example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 6212 in 2016 for  the last line doesn't seems right, for the rest a dynamic `PIVOT` can solve this.

The basic idea is to generate the future payments in columns

```
WITH N(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
       , ID = u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
), H (freq, times)  AS (
  SELECT 'WK', 52 UNION ALL SELECT 'MX', 12
)
SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
     , _Year
     , yearPayment = Payments 
     * ((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + H.times) / 2
     - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID - H.times) / 2)
FROM   Data d
       INNER JOIN H ON d.Frequency = H.freq
       CROSS JOIN Y
WHERE  PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID > 0
ORDER BY AccountNo, _Year
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58822/16)</kbd>

with `N` and `Y` to generate the future years.
`H` as an helper table that store the number of payment will be made in a year for the frequency type (I hope those are static).
`((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + H.times) / 2 - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID - H.times) / 2)` calculate the minimum between `PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID` and `H.times` using the formula `(A + B) / 2 - ABS(A - B) / 2`

then using a `PIVOT` to transform the columns to rows, below is a test query with a limited number of years

```
WITH N(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
       , ID = u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
), H (freq, times)  AS (
  SELECT 'WK', 52 UNION ALL SELECT 'MX', 12
)
SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
     , [2014], [2015], [2016], [2017]
FROM   (SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
             , _Year
             , yearPayment = Payments 
             * ((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + H.times) / 2
             - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID - H.times) / 2)
        FROM   Data d
               INNER JOIN H ON d.Frequency = H.freq
               CROSS JOIN Y
        WHERE  PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID > 0) D
       PIVOT
       (MAX(yearPayment) FOR _Year IN ([2014], [2015], [2016], [2017])) pvt
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58822/19)</kbd>

that can be made dynamic

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

WITH N(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([_Year])
                      FROM Y
                      ORDER BY _Year
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')
SELECT @query ='
WITH N(N) AS (
          SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7
UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
       , ID = u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
), H (freq, times)  AS (
  SELECT ''WK'', 52 UNION ALL SELECT ''MX'', 12
)
SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
     , ' + @cols + '
FROM   (SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
             , _Year
             , yearPayment = Payments 
             * ((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + H.times) / 2
             - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID - H.times) / 2)
        FROM   Data d
               INNER JOIN H ON d.Frequency = H.freq
               CROSS JOIN Y
        WHERE  PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID > 0) D
       PIVOT
       (MAX(yearPayment) FOR _Year IN (' + @cols + ')) pvt'

execute(@query);
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58822/26)</kbd>

---

If there is a lag between the beginning of the first year and the beginning of the payment that information can be stored in an additional `CTE` in the same form of the `H` `CTE`, for example with a lag of six month the values will be 26 weeks and 6 month, those values will be added to the payment left at the end of the year, so the formula for the remaining payment change from

```
PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID
```

to

```
PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times
```

the base query, with a few year, became

```
WITH N(N) AS (
  SELECT N FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) D(N)
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
       , ID = u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
), H (freq, times)  AS (
  SELECT 'WK', 52 UNION ALL SELECT 'MX', 12
), L (freq, times) AS (
  SELECT 'WK', 26 UNION ALL SELECT 'MX', 6
)  
SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
     , [2014], [2015], [2016], [2017], [2018]
FROM   (SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
             , _Year
             , yearPayment = Payments 
             * (((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times + H.times) / 2
             - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times - H.times) / 2)
             - CASE WHEN _Year = Year(SYSDATETIME()) THEN L.Times
                    ELSE 0
               END)

        FROM   Data d
               INNER JOIN H ON d.Frequency = H.freq
               INNER JOIN L ON d.Frequency = L.freq
               CROSS JOIN Y
        WHERE  PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times > 0) D
       PIVOT
       (MAX(yearPayment) FOR _Year IN ([2014], [2015], [2016], [2017])) pvt
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58822/40)</kbd>

the dynamic form is

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

WITH N(N) AS (
  SELECT N FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) D(N)
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
)
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([_Year])
                      FROM Y
                      ORDER BY _Year
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '')

SELECT @query ='
WITH N(N) AS (
  SELECT N FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
                      , (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) D(N)
), Y AS (
  SELECT _Year = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) + u.N + t.N * 10
       , ID = u.N + t.N * 10
  FROM   N u
         CROSS JOIN N t
  WHERE  u.N + t.N * 10 < 20
), H (freq, times)  AS (
  SELECT ''WK'', 52 UNION ALL SELECT ''MX'', 12
), L (freq, times) AS (
  SELECT ''WK'', 26 UNION ALL SELECT ''MX'', 6
)  
SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
     , ' + @cols + '
FROM   (SELECT AccountNo, Balance, Payments, Frequency, PaymentsRemaining
             , _Year
             , yearPayment = Payments 
             * (((PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times + H.times) / 2
             - ABS(PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times - H.times) / 2)
             - CASE WHEN _Year = Year(SYSDATETIME()) THEN L.Times
                    ELSE 0
               END)

        FROM   Data d
               INNER JOIN H ON d.Frequency = H.freq
               INNER JOIN L ON d.Frequency = L.freq
               CROSS JOIN Y
        WHERE  PaymentsRemaining - H.times * ID + L.times > 0) D
       PIVOT
       (MAX(yearPayment) FOR _Year IN (' + @cols + ')) pvt'

execute(@query);
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58822/41)</kbd>

Comment: This is fantastic however I now need to find a way to exclude the first half of this year from the query. I figured out how to do the whole year. but not half. Any pointers?